# variable is not properly set after renaming into heir

Tags: eiffel, void-safety

I know how to fix it (see my solution @bottom) but don't understand why this compilation error occurs, as in my mind, renamed attributes should be created by the Precursor into default_create. Why isn't that so?

### NRJ_ENTITY

```
inherit
    ANY
        redefine
            default_create
        end

feature {NONE} -- Initialization

    default_create
        do
            create current_day
            create current_month
            create current_year
            Precursor
        end

feature -- Access

    current_day,
    current_month,
    current_year: ENERGY_UNIT

end
```

### NRJ_CONSUMER

```
inherit
    NRJ_ENTITY

end
```

### NRJ_GENERATOR

```
inherit
    NRJ_ENTITY

end
```

### NRJ_GENERATOR_CONSUMER

```
inherit
    NRJ_GENERATOR
        rename
            current_day as current_day_generation,
            current_month as current_month_generation,
            current_year as current_year_generation
        redefine
            default_create
        select
            current_day_generation,
            current_month_generation,
            current_year_generation
        end
    NRJ_CONSUMER
        rename
            current_day as current_day_consumption,
            current_month as current_month_consumption,
            current_year as current_year_consumption
        redefine
            default_create
        end

feature {NONE} -- Initialize

    default_create
        do
            Precursor {NRJ_GENERATOR}
            Precursor {NRJ_CONSUMER}
        end
```

end

### Error screenshot

[image]

### Fix into NRJ_GENERATOR_CONSUMER

```
default_create
    do
        create current_day_consumption
        create current_month_consumption
        create current_year_consumption
        Precursor {NRJ_CONSUMER}
        Precursor {NRJ_GENERATOR}
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `NRJ_GENERATOR_CONSUMER` has two versions of every attribute from `NRJ_ENTITY`. For example, `current_day` has versions `current_day_generation` and `current_day_consumption`. The code in `NRJ_ENTITY` works only with one version of `current_day`, possibly renamed. It has no idea about the second version. In order to tell which version of the replicated attribute (or a feature, in general) should be used, the class with the replication should `select` exactly one suitable version.

In the example, the selected version is `current_day_generation`. Therefore, `default_create` inherited from `NRJ_ENTITY` initializes it and not the other attribute. In other words, with replication,

```
create current_day
```

is not automatically translated into

```
create current_day_generation
create current_day_consumption
```

but just into

```
create current_day_generation -- The selected version.
```

This explains why you need the fix you are referring to.

Also, note that the instructions `Precursor {NRJ_CONSUMER}` and `Precursor {NRJ_GENERATOR}` call exactly the same version of `default_create` defined in `NRJ_ENTITY`, so one of the calls can be safely removed.

**Summary:** Inherited code deals only with selected versions of replicated features.

**Corollary:** Non-selected versions of replicated attributes have to be explicitly initialized in the class where they are replicated.

Comment: Many thx, should't be a best practice to keep both `Precursor` calls in case a redfinition is made into one of the parents?

Comment: @Pipo It depends on the application. For example, if the creation procedure opens a file, it might be problematic to call the procedure twice.